# React Redux State is Updating, but Component Props Not Updating

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, render

Disclaimer: this is my first react app and im a cs student thats still learning

I did some console logs and the the props and nextprops are correct, but it doesnt render correctly unless interacted with.

I have to click a button twice before the opacity changes and the opacity of the other buttons doesnt update to 1.

I've gone through quite a few google searches and tried a few things, but none of them worked.

**Class with 2 instances of the button from WeekMenu.js**

```
class WeekMenu extends Component{
render(){
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity 
            style={this.props.daysOfWeek[0] ? {opacity: 0.5} : {opacity: 1}}
            onPress={() =>this.props.dayClicked(0)}
            >
                <View style={styles.left}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>S</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity 
            style={this.props.daysOfWeek[1] ? {opacity: 0.5} : {opacity: 1}}
            onPress={() =>this.props.dayClicked(1)}
            >
                <View style={styles.middle}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>M</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

**WeekMenu.js contiued**

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
        daysOfWeek: state.daysOfWeek
    }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return{
        dayClicked: (value) => dispatch({type: 'DAY_CLICKED', value})
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WeekMenu)
```

**App.js**

```
const initialState = {
    daysOfWeek: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
}
changeActiveDay = (day) => {
    newDaysOfWeek = new Array(7).fill(0)
    newDaysOfWeek[day] = 1
    return newDaysOfWeek
}
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'DAY_CLICKED':
            return {
                ...state,
                daysOfWeek: changeActiveDay(action.value)
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
const store = createStore(reducer)
```

**Update #1:**

```
class WeekMenu extends Component{
state = {
    daysOfWeek: this.props.daysOfWeek
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    if(prevProps.daysOfWeek !== this.props.daysOfWeek)
        this.setState({daysOfWeek: this.props.daysOfWeek})
}

render(){
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity 
            style={this.state.daysOfWeek[0] ? {opacity: 0.5} : {opacity: 1}}
            onPress={() => this.props.dayClicked(0)}
            >
                <View style={styles.left}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>S</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            ...
```

Comment: check componentwillrecieveprops

Comment: Can you create a codepen for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen the changes using `componentWillUpdate()` or `shouldComponentUpdate()` and listen to the changes using `nextProps` and `prevState` as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lifecycle to set your props to state.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) { 
  this.setDaysOfWeek(prevProps, prevState)
}


setDaysOfWeek(prevProps,state) {
  if(prevProps.daysOfWeek !== state.daysOfWeek){
    this.setState({daysOfWeek: prevProps.daysOfWeek})   
  }
}
```

Comment: I added this code to my WeekMenu.js (see Update #1). I console.log a bunch of things and the state and props are both being updated on click. The button's opacity still doesnt change on click. It changes after two clicks and it only updates for that specific single button. I think theres a problem with the style={...} updating after state and props changes.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from peer:

Include this line of code before the style is set to force a rerender by changing an unused key to a random number

```
key={String(Math.random())}
```

As in this example:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    key={String(Math.random())}
    style={this.state.daysOfWeek[index] ? {opacity: 0.5} : {opacity: 1}}
    onPress={() => this.props.dayClicked(index)}
>
```